# Add an attribute to the <HTML> element in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, xml-namespaces

I would like to add two additional xml namespaces to the `<HTML>` element in asp.net:

take:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
```

to make (adding facebook open graph namespaces):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
      xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

How would I access the `<HTML>` element in code behind and add a namespace?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do it just like any other element.  In your aspx just mark the html tag to be runat server:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" id="html_tag" runat="server">
```

And in your code just add the attributes:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   html_tag.Attributes.Add("xmlns:og","http://ogp.me/ns#");
   html_tag.Attributes.Add("xmlns:fb", "http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbmls");
}
```

This of course does not have to be done via code and can just be placed in your aspx unless you wanted to only include those attributes in certain conditions.

Comment: glad i asked before i over thunk it.  :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like as below:

```
<html <%= GetTags() %> >
```

The GetTags function will be defined in your code behind file and should return a string which will be placed in html tag, so you can return the "tags" as string and it will appear in HTML tag.

But I am not getting your point of doing this from code behind. Why not just do it in the aspx itself?

Answer (score 0):

I hope it is helpful. How to set "enabled/disabled" for a button:

```
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md remove-button" <%=GetDisabledGtmlAttribute(IsUIDisabled) %>>>Remove</button>
```

C#:

```
  protected string GetDisabledGtmlAttribute(bool isUIDisabled)
    {
        if (isUIDisabled)
        {
            return "disabled";
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
```